# Message page not found for few css and js files in Spring MVC project

Tags: javascript, css

I an unable to access the few of CSS and JS files in my SPring MVC project. Below are the code in jsp page.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" href="/css/demopage.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" href="/css/demo_table.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" href="/css/demo_table_jui.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" href="/css/jquery-ui-1.8.24.custom.css" />
<script src="/javascript/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascript/jquery_dataTables.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

It is able to access style.css and jquery.js files where as other files are not found but they have been kept with the these files only.

Comment: try with the correct closing process </link>

Comment: @KarthikSivakumar **WHAT?**

Comment: I have tried several times using close brace. But every time I get page not found message.

Comment: Do the files you are trying to access actually exist?

Comment: @Askanison4 It is able to access style.css where as other css files placed inside the same directory are not accessible.

Comment: Could you try removing the closing "/" from each of the `<link>` tags?

Comment: @Askanison4 I tried. But still the same problem. It accesses style.css and jquery.js files while others are page not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recheck your paths. if it's dynamic, you probably need spring MVC specific linking.

Comment: It is able to access style.css where as other css files placed inside the same directory are not accessible.

Comment: Weird, well there is a work around.... have your style css @import url('') the other css's. Thats best practice anyways. This way you only have one server call.
Hopefully this helps :)